# Problema con hilos java

Tags: java, hilos

no sé muy bien como conseguir que al ejecutar me aparezca algo parecido a:

> Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 1
>   El hilo main (padre) ha terminado su ejecución
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 2
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 3
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 1
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 4
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 5
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 2
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 6
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 3
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 7
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 4
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 8
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 5
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 9
>   Hilo1 está ejecutando la tarea 10
>   Hilo1 ha completado su ejecución
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 6
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 7
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 8
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 9
>   Hilo2 está ejecutando la tarea 10

Tengo esta estructura pero no sé muy bien como implementarla.

```
public class Principal {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        HilosVarios hilo1 = new HilosVarios();

        HilosVarios2 hilo2 = new HilosVarios2(hilo1);
        hilo1.start();
        hilo2.start();
        System.out.println("Terminadas las tareas");
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. He arreglado el formato de tu pregunta, pero el código ue has puesto tiene errores sintácticos y no está claro qué se supone que hace. Mira [mcve] y dale a "editar" para corregir el código. Además, la pregunta no está muy clara (por la descripción del problema, basta con que hagas un montón de `System.out.println` uno detrás de otro). En todo caso, podría ser que te interesara informarte sobre concurrencia en Java, específicamente los *Executors*.

Comment: Tal y como veo el código, te tiene que salir error de sintaxis por lo menos, simplemente con las llaves.

Comment: Aunque implementes runnable, tienes que hacer un new Thread (this) blablabla y en el main llamar al run y te falta muchísimo código...

Comment: No esta claro que realiza HilosVarios e HilosVarios2, pero deberían ser una extensión de __Thread__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes crear hilos de diferentes maneras. O bien extendiendo la clase `Thread` o implementado `Runnable`

**Extendiendo la clase Thread..**

```
    class ThreadEjemplo extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ejecutando Thread \'ThreadEjemplo\': " +i);
        }
    }

}
```

Y lo llamamos así..

```
//Arranca un nuevo hilo. Clase ThreadEjemplo
new ThreadEjemplo().start();
```

---

**Implementado Runnable...**

```
class RunnableEjemplo implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ejecutando Thread \'RunnableEjemplo\': " +i);
        }
    }

}
```

Y lo llamamos así..

```
new Thread(new RunnableEjemplo()).start();
```

Nuestra clase que implementa `Runnable` se lo pasamos como parámetro a una instancia de `Thread`

---

**Ejemplo al completo..**

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Arranca un nuevo hilo. Clase ThreadEjemplo
        new ThreadEjemplo().start();

        //Arranca otro hilo con la clase que implementa Runnable
        new Thread(new RunnableEjemplo()).start();

        System.out.println("El hilo main (padre) ha terminado su ejecución");
    }
}

class ThreadEjemplo extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ejecutando Thread \'ThreadEjemplo\': " +i);
        }
    }

}

class RunnableEjemplo implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ejecutando Thread \'RunnableEjemplo\': " +i);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Si quieres verlo con más detenimiento a la hora de ejecutarlos, puedes llamar al método estático **sleep()** - `Thread.sleep(1);`, dentro de los respectivos bucle for encerrándolos dentro de un bloque `try - catch`

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("El thread ha sido detenido");
            }

            System.out.println("Ejecutando Thread \'ThreadEjemplo\': " + i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y sabiendo que Runnable es una interfaz funcional también se podría hacer de una manera simplificada mediante lambdas.

Comment: Si llamas `Thread.sleep(1)` en cualquier parte del código lo que vas a detener es el hilo principal y por ende bloquear todo el programa. Tendrías que llamar a `miInstanciaDeHilo.sleep(1)`